Cannot install psycopg2 or psycopg2-binary using pip
Normally I use macos, for my work I just started to use windows. Tried to install psycopg2 and it failed. Also tried to install psycopg2-binary and that failed too.
When I type pip install psycopg2-binary error message is like this:
Collecting psycopg2-binary
  Using cached psycopg2-binary-2.9.10.tar.gz (385 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [5 lines of output]
      running egg_info
      writing psycopg2_binary.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to psycopg2_binary.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to psycopg2_binary.egg-info\top_level.txt
      error: [WinError 2] Sistem belirtilen dosyayı bulamıyor
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

What should I do to properly install this hella lib?

Please add the exact setup to the description. Python version, windows version, psycopg2 version you are trying to install, environment type. It makes easier to help

I'm betting it is related to Windows/Python 3.13.

You may need to translate "Sistem belirtilen dosyayı bulamıyor" for us

@Robert "Sistem belirtilen dosyayı bulamıyor" means "The system cannot find the specified file".

Python 3.13.0, Windows 11 Pro 21H2 22000.2538, psycopg2-binary-2.9.10 and using virtual env (venv) @ranemak

Yes " error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the specified file", thank you and sorry for the late reply

Also I am using Visual Studio Version: 1.95.2

I think you are right @AdrianKlaver

Gonna downgrade to Python3.12
